# How to find specific content within an external webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm basically trying to check whether an array of web-sites has the content that I'm looking for, using Javascript and a Node.js server. I don't mind if JQuery is needed, just not sure how to go about this. For example, whether the web-sites "www.skysports.com" and "www.bbc.co.uk" have the word "football" somewhere in the visible content of their web-site. Should this be done by running a method through the source code?

The list of web-sites will be extended so was therefore looking to pass an array of web-sites into a method that would then pass the results into a table displaying true or false.

```
if (
(
document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText
).indexOf('Football') > -1
) {
  return true
}
else {
  return false
}
```

This is what I've got so far, although I know that this will only work on an internal document, I figured that if I pull down the source code of the external web-site, I could run something like this on the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
var http = require('http');

function checkSites(sites, keyword) {
  sites.forEach(function(site) {
    var request = http.request({host: site}, function (res) {
      var html = '';
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        html += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(site, html.indexOf(keyword) > -1);
      });
    }).end();
  });
}

checkSites(['www.skysports.com', 'www.bbc.co.uk'], 'Football');
```

That just checks the html. Honestly you should probably be using something like [zombie js](http://zombie.js.org/) to render the html / javascript of each site and then check the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running jQuery `$.get("http://www.domain.com");` function?

[jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did think of using this function, but wanted to ideally keep it purely Javascript.